# Woo Как передать значение при переходе с "Карточки товара №1" на "Карточку товара №2"

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Подскажите, как бы реализовали такой функционал?
Вариативный товар в Woo. Находимся в "Карточке товара №1" на которой ссылка, при клике на ссылку, выводит покупателя на "Карточку товара №2" т.е. переход по ссылке, НО если мы в "Карточке товара №1" выбрали цвет: "Зеленый", то при переходе на "Карточку товара №2" мы перейдем на дефолтное значение вариативного товара цвет "Синий", а не на цвет: "Зеленый".

Вопрос: "Как реализовать переход из "Карточки товара №1" в "Карточку товара №2" при этом сохранить выбранные опции цвета: "Зеленый" - "Зеленый"

Заранее благодарю.

Comment: Самый простой путь привязать событие на клик/смену цвета товара 1 смену  ссылки на товар 2, которая ведет не нужный цвет товара 2.

Answer (score 1):

Сначала надо разобраться в том, как сформировать ссылку на конкретный вариант товара. Допустим, ваш вариативный товар имеет атрибут Color со значениями Blue, Red, White. Тогда ссылка на товар синего цвета выглядит так:

```
http://test.kagg.eu/product/quia-qui-atque-quia-magnam/?attribute_pa_color=blue
```

Можете проверить её на моём тестовом сайте. Подстроки `attribute` и `pa` должны присутствовать всегда, остальное зависит от значений для вашего товара.

Теперь становится понятна последовательность действий:

- ставим обработчик `onclick` на ссылку на Товар 2
- по клику считываем выбранное пользователем значение атрибута текущего товара из `select id="pa_color"`
- правим ссылку на Товар 2, чтобы она приобрела вид, описанный в начале ответа
- осуществляем переход с помощью `window.location.href`

Comment: Да, но ссылка имеет вид: ....../product/bluza-sky-color/ и при выборе цвета не изменяется в таком случае, может как-то через Cookie реализовать?